# SSIS: Using send email based on rowcount of CSV file

Tags: csv, ssis, package, dataflow, rowcount

I have a dataflow task that looks at a CSV file in a folder and counts the number of rows into a variable (Flat file source directly to row count). The variable is called `User::RowCount`

The control flow part basically has 2 send mail tasks. What I am trying to do is the following:

- When the CSV file has more than 0 rows, use the send mail task on the left.
- When the CSV file has 0 rows, use the send mail task on the right. This is what I have set up:

It was all working fine with the constraint I had configured and then after a few weeks I started receiving the "error" email, checked the CSV and there's actually 1 row in there and not 0, the left send mail task should have triggered.

The constraint for the success mail task (left) is: 
Evaluation operation: Expression

Expression:

```
@[User::RowCount] != 0
```

The constraint for the fail mail task (right) is:
Evaluation operation: Expression

Expression:

```
@[User::RowCount] == 0
```

I have a feeling it's wrong but I don't know where! Images are here:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe check your Flat File Connection Manager, go to the Text Qualifier, see if there is anything like this "_x0022_", it drops one row. This happens when moving a package from 32bit to 64bit system. (Ps, I can't see the link unfortunately. Blocked where I am.)

Comment: I'm so stupid - I hadn't realised that I selected the first row to be considered as headers, I've just unchecked that so hopefully it should work fine now! Thank you!

Comment: @JayP Worth popping an answer in and marking as answered?